# multiple instance of a same resolver in spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

i have two view folder how can i manage a same resolver that can find a way to its resolver?
i try this but this is not working

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/view/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="adminViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/view/admin/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

i will be greatfull for any help that can i learn what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need two resolvers. One can make all the job:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

and then comes your controller:

```
//this one will be mapped as /view/index.jsp
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("view/index");
        return mv;
    }



//this one will be mapped as /view/admin/index.jsp
@RequestMapping(value="/admin.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("view/admin/index");
        return mv;
    }
```

Alternatively, you can map it as two separate controllers using `@RequestMapping(value="/view")` and `@RequestMapping(value="/view/admin")`

Comment: thanks.it works!i am beginner and maybe my question is awfull .thanks again